# How display em dash character in qt label?

Tags: c++, qt, hash

I want to set label and marker  for y axis ticks in GUI. so I use dash character to mark ticks such:

```
label_1->setText(QString("10mv -");
```

the dash line in small so I use em dash :

```
label_1->setText(QString("10mv ─");
```

when GUI run instead of "─" I see "?" 
How can I show em dash in Qt GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'em dash' is a unicode character so try using this:

```
label_1->setText(QString::fromStdWString(L"10mv ─"));
```

It worked for me.